# Save extended tweet to CSV with Tweepy?

Tags: python, csv, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to use Tweepy to save extended tweets to a CSV file, but the tweets only continue to show until the 140 character limit. I set the truncated parameter to False and tweet_mode to "extended," but I still can't get the full tweets to display in the CSV file. Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tweepy
import csv #Import csv
auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('XXX', 'XXX')
auth.set_access_token('XXX', 'XXX')

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Open/create a file to append data to
csvFile = open('file.csv', 'a')

#Use csv writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q = "query",
                           truncated = False,
                           tweet_mode= "extended",
                           since = "2019-12-11",
                           until = "2019-12-18",
                           wait_on_rate_limit = True,
                           lang = "en").items():
    if (not tweet.retweeted) and ('RT @' not in tweet.full_text):  
        csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')])
        print(tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text)
csvFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Passing parameters into the API method section of the Cursor Tutorial](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/cursor_tutorial.html#passing-parameters-into-the-api-method), keyword arguments fed to `tweepy.Cursor()` will be passed along to `api.search` when it is called.

However, **the `api.search` method does not take a `tweet_mode` keyword argument** - see [`API.search`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#help-methods) in the tweepy documentation. In fact, the only API endpoint that uses it seems to be [`api.lookup_users()`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API.lookup_users) (see [source code](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/ce2ad288166a72d53cfe5cbc33f0ff8b333379b4/tweepy/api.py#L376)).

In other words, it seems that the `tweet_mode="extended"` keyword argument is simply being ignored by the `api.search` method. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/ce2ad288166a72d53cfe5cbc33f0ff8b333379b4/tweepy/api.py#L1270-L1272) it is not used in the final API call.

**Two suggestions:**

1. If the `tweet_mode` keyword argument is not actually implemented, you may need to file a bug report in the [tweepy repo on Github](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy).
2. Alternatively, try splitting your code into two steps: in the first step, use `api.search` to get a list of tweet IDs that match your search. Then, use the resulting list of tweet IDs and call `api.get_status` as per [this example](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extended_tweets.html#examples). If their example does not work, that's a good place to start with your bug report in the tweepy repo!

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I now get this attribute error: 'Status' object has no attribute 'full_text'

Comment: Is that coming from the results of the `get_status()` call using the first [extended tweets](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extended_tweets.html#examples) example?